# defining class vars in modules in crystal causes error

Tags: crystal-lang

I am trying to define a class variable inside my module, but I'm getting an error that the type of @@blub cannot be inferred, even though I have explicitly declared the type:

```
module Bla
  @@blub : Int32 = 0

  def add_blub(a : Int32)
    @@blub += a
  end

  def blub
    @@blub
  end
end

class Blub
  extend Bla
end

Blub.add_blub 1
puts Blub.blub
```

The error I get is

```
Error in line 17: instantiating 'Blub:Class#add_blub(Int32)'

in line 5: Can't infer the type of class variable '@@blub' of Blub

The type of a class variable, if not declared explicitly with
`@@blub : Type`, is inferred from assignments to it across
the whole program.

The assignments must look like this:

  1. `@@blub = 1` (or other literals), inferred to the literal's type
  2. `@@blub = Type.new`, type is inferred to be Type
  3. `@@blub = Type.method`, where `method` has a return type
     annotation, type is inferred from it
  4. `@@blub = arg`, with 'arg' being a method argument with a
     type restriction 'Type', type is inferred to be Type
  5. `@@blub = arg`, with 'arg' being a method argument with a
     default value, type is inferred using rules 1, 2 and 3 from it
  6. `@@blub = uninitialized Type`, type is inferred to be Type
  7. `@@blub = LibSome.func`, and `LibSome` is a `lib`, type
     is inferred from that fun.
  8. `LibSome.func(out @@blub)`, and `LibSome` is a `lib`, type
     is inferred from that fun argument.

Other assignments have no effect on its type.

Can't infer the type of class variable '@@blub' of Blub
```

I tried different ways of defining this, any idea what might cause this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `extend` does not include class variables. The [language reference](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/modules.html) does not mention this, but it looks to be an error (see [#4066](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/4066)).

It works however if you also `include Bla` (though that's probably not what you want) or define the class variable in an `extended` macro hook:

```
macro extended
  @@blub : Int32 = 0
end
```

[carc.in](https://carc.in/#/r/2ifv)